# How to create react app using create-react-app with reactjs 15 version

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a project which is written 3 years ago in reactjs 15 version and also it is single tier architecture project. I am right now converting it to 3 tier project architecture. So I thought of having the react part alone. My question is how should I create a reactJS folder structure using the new create-react-app and add the already existing code into it. I know this question might be broad. But any steps will help me to better understand the structure to be followed in react. Its been like only 2 months I am learning reactjs.

```
"react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.8",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-flipcard": "^0.2.1",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.16",
    "react-pdf": "^2.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-stars": "^2.2.5",
    "react-table": "^6.7.4",
    "react-tabs-navigation": "^0.4.4",
    "react-toastr": "^2.8.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.63.5",
    "superagent": "^3.8.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "x-frame-options": "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: I mean you can just run CRA inside your project root and let CRA create a new folder called `/web/` or `/react/` for you where your react set-up would be located?

Comment: There is no structure that is required for React and the most "official" I ever heard recommendation was to "move stuff around until it feels right". So, no "structure to be followed in react" ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to make **components** folder in **src** folder. There you can structure components to atoms, molecules, organisms, templates and pages if you are a fan of a Atomic design as I am. From there every component should be separated in separate folder and have **component.types.js/ts**, **component.constants.js/ts**, **component.scss**, **component.js/tsx**. Types would refer to prop and any other types related to that component. Constants, components and scss file are quite obvious as for what they are used. Also you can have **test** folder in every component where you can write tests.

Also you can have **common** folder in **src** where you can put your utility files, for example custom hooks, http setup etc.

Another important folder in **src** is **config**. All config your app needs can be in there in different files if that is needed.

Last but not the least is **assests** foloder inside **src**. As name suggests you put all of your static assets (fonts, images, videos...).

I think this is very good basis to start from and expand your folder structure as you see fit and as project is needed. Also none of this i strict to naming but those are some conventions that you can read [here](https://dev.to/sanfra1407/how-to-organize-your-components-using-the-atomic-design-dj3).

```
awesome-app
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── atoms
│   │   │   ├── button
│   │   │   │   ├── button.types.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── button.component.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── button.constants.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── button.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── test
│   │   │   │        ├── button.test.tsx
│   │   │   │        └── ...
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── molecules
│   │   │   ├── action-card
│   │   │   │   ├── action-card.types.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── action-card.component.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── action-card.constants.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── action-card.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── test
│   │   │   │        ├── action-card.test.tsx
│   │   │   │        └── ...
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── organisms
│   │   │   ├── school-module-row
│   │   │   │   ├── school-module-row.types.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── school-module-row.component.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── school-module-row.constants.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── school-module-row.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── test
│   │   │   │        ├── school-module-row.test.tsx
│   │   │   │        └── ...
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── pages
│   │   │   ├── users-page
│   │   │   │   ├── users-page.types.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── users-page.component.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── users-page.constants.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── users-page.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── test
│   │   │   │        ├── users-page.test.tsx
│   │   │   │        └── ...
│   │   │   └── ...
│   ├── styles
│   │   ├── base
│   │   │   ├── _base.scss
│   │   │   ├── _font.scss
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   │   
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │    └── ...
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │    └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── config
│   │   └── ...
│   └── redux
          └── actions
          └── ...
```